# How to handle csrf in RTK Query? How do I access XSRF-token?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, csrf, redux-toolkit

So in angular I can manage the csrf very easily.
But how do I do it in react redux tool kit query?
In create endpoint I use credentials: "include". But I can't access the token neither I see it in the cookies.

How this safety token is getting handled?

[image]
(the xsrf-token is not http only and not secure)